# Client\Server App using MFC Document\View model?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am looking for ideas on how to architect an MDI database (client\server) application using MFC.

I am working on an MFC\C++ database application that was architected many years ago around MFC's MDI Document\View model.  The "documents" are persisted to a set of relational database tables.  Although MFC's Document\View model was not designed for a database application the app managed to cobble together a way to make it work and to look like documents to the user.

I have read a few articles on using MFC for a database app and there is even a Database App Wizard in MFC.  However, the examples all look very light weight, simplistic and dated (e.g., from 2004).

Is MFC even a viable option for a database (client server app)?  Is the document\view model a dead end from the start?

Thanks in advance